# Missing font symbols for operators

Tags: fonts, xetex, unicode, unicode-math, math-fonts

I'd like to print operators such as union and intersection (\bigcup and \bigcap) in math mode, but apparently they are missing from the Fira Math fonts I'm currently using for my beamer document. I think that this is the case because I get boxed interrogative points in the PDF output after compiling. I'm using XeLaTeX. So, is there a way to take such glyphs from the default Computer Modern font family?

MWE:

```
% !TeX program = xelatex

\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{FiraSans}
\usepackage{FiraMono}

\usepackage[mathrm=sym,warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket}]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Fira Math Regular}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[range=frak]

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
            \[
            \bigcap \bigcup
            \]
        \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution here: [Using a fancy font for mathmode, falling back to XITS for missing symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37658/using-a-fancy-font-for-mathmode-falling-back-to-xits-for-missing-symbols?rq=1)

Just adding the desired commands to the range of \setmathfont does the trick:

```
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[range={frak,\bigcap,\bigcup}]
```

I guess something similar applies to other operators such as \bigoplus, \prod, \sum, etc.